spreadsheet testing schedule got back 1899
could anyone please tell me why my appscript and my schedule
keeps telling me i'm booked for 1899, when where in 2024
// Function to send email with image and booking details
function sendEmailWithImage(Username, Timeslot, Day) {
  var imageObject = {};
  var successImageLoading = true;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Schedule');
  var emailAddress = "coolvibes1989@gmail.com"; // Your email
  var subject = "Presenter Booked";

  // Use try-catch to handle errors while loading the image
  try {
    imageObject['myImage1'] = DriveApp.getFileById('1oin8reV7pvZZ9kewuYYw-z4lAFf233YI').getAs('image/png');
  } catch (error) {
    successImageLoading = false;
  }

  // Ensure Day is a Date object
  if (!(Day instanceof Date)) {
    Logger.log("Day is not a valid Date object: " + Day);
    return; // Exit the function if Day is invalid
  }

  // Convert the Day and Timeslot into a human-readable format
  var dayFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(Day, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "mm dd yy");  // e.g., "Saturday, Oct 07 2023"
  var timeFormatted = Timeslot; // Assuming Timeslot is already in a readable format; adjust as needed

  // Create HTML content for the email
  var htmlStartString = "<html><head><style type='text/css'> table {border-collapse: collapse; display: block;} th {border: 1px solid black; background-color:blue; color: white;} td {border: 1px solid black;} #body a {color: inherit !important; text-decoration: none !important; font-size: inherit !important; font-family: inherit !important; font-weight: inherit !important; line-height: inherit !important;}</style></head><body id='body'>";
  var htmlEndString = "</body></html>";

  // Message content with Username, Timeslot, and Day
  var message = `Slot Booked! Thank you ${Username} for booking. Your slot is scheduled for ${dayFormatted}, ${timeFormatted}.`;

  var emailBody = `${htmlStartString}<p>${message}</p>`;

  // Include image in the email body if image loading is successful
  if (successImageLoading) {
    emailBody += `<p><img src='cid:myImage1' style='width:400px; height:auto;' ></p>`;
  }

  emailBody += htmlEndString;

  // Debugging log
  Logger.log(emailBody);  // This will show the email body in the Logs for debugging

  // Send email
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: emailBody,
    inlineImages: (successImageLoading ? imageObject : null)
  });
}

// Trigger function for On Change event
function onChange(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Schedule');
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();

  if (col >= 3 && col <= 9) { // Check if the change is within the schedule columns (C to H)
    var Username = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue(); // Get the presenter's name
    var Timeslot = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue(); // Get the time from column B
    var Day = sheet.getRange(4, col).getValue(); // Get the day from row 4 (header)

    // Convert Day if it's not already a Date object
    if (typeof Day === "string") {
      Day = new Date(Day); // Convert string to Date
    }

    if (Username) {
      // Call the sendEmailWithImage function with the Username, Timeslot, and Day
      sendEmailWithImage(Username, Timeslot, Day);
    }
  }
}


schedule
i tried adding different lines of code to the date in lowercase mm, dd, yy
instead of caps, tested the spreadsheet schedule again still telling me
i'm booked for 1899
the result came into email as booked a slot for 1899

If your date has a numeric value of 0, spreadsheets typically consider it to be a date of 12/31/1899 at 00:00 AM (midnight).

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question is missing relevant information as to what parameters the functions is being called with. Please add a [mre].

Chances are that you are calling the function with a Day that is a time or duration instead of a date. When the date portion is missing in a datetime, it defaults to Google Sheets epoch, i.e., 1899-12-31.
Make Day point to a cell that contains a date to fix it.
See Working with date and time values in Google Sheets and Working with Dates and Times in Apps Script.
